# Difference between org.mockito.Mockito.any and org.mockito.matchers.any?

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito, tdd

I am realizing that in my project I am using two libraries that, essentially, do the same thing:

1) **org.mockito.Mockito.any**

2) **org.mockito.Matchers.any**

I'd like to use just one of them to be clearer, which one should I stick to?

Thanks!

Comment: Why downvotes? :-| At least leave a reason...

Comment: The question doesn't show any research effort. Noticing that the former is a subclass of the latter is easy - its just opening the class and having a look at it.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker just because _you_ noticed that fact, or that you think that noticing that fact "is easy" (the implication being that an answer can be gleaned by the OP once this information is attained), does not at all correlate with the level of research effort that can be inferred from the question.  People don't come here seeking help on things that they find easy.  While I acknowledge that you aren't claiming to answer the question, hence the comment vs answer, your comment implies that you had the skills to answer and chose not to.  No offence intended, but that's poor form in my book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Mockito` is a sub class of `Matchers` that's why you can still access the parent's static method like you did.

So I suggest you stick with `Matchers.any()` since that is where the implementation is located.

Comment: Thanks, what about org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any? Is related with them in the same way?

Comment: Somewhat related, ie. `Mockito.any` and all other `Mockito.any**` are just an `ArgumentMatchers` implementation.